# Storyboard labels constraints

Tags: swift, storyboard, constraints

I have 4 labels on my storyboard, aligned at baseline and with fixed distance between them.
Each label can have different values at runtime, and I would like that the group of these 4 labels is horizontally centered.

Didn't succeed to fix it !
I tried to put them in a view and center the view, but it doesn't work either.
Tried also to play with priorities, but didn't't succeed either...

Is it possible to achieve that in the storyboard ?

Comment: What you're probably looking for is a stack view.

Comment: I agree with Justin. This is a fair pain to do without a stack view, and trivial to do **with** a stack view.

Comment: This solution is working if the distance between each label is fixed, but if they are different, the stack view does not allow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by putting your 4 labels inside of another view.  Add the following constraints:

1. Set fixed distance constraints between the labels (3 constraints).
2. Set constraints to align the baselines of the labels (3 constraints).
3. Set a leading constraint from the leftmost label to the containing view.  Set the constant to `0`.
4. Set a trailing constraint from the rightmost label to the containing view.  Set the constant to `0`.
5. Set a constraint for the height of the view.
6. Set a constraint from the top of the left label to the top of its containing view.
7. Set a constraint to center the view horizontally.
8. Set a constraint to position the view vertically.

The width of the view will be determined by the intrinsic sizes of the labels plus the sizes of the distances in #1.  This width will change as the contents of the labels changes, and the view will keep the group centered.

---

[image: Showing constraints in Storyboard]

Comment: @Eric, did you try this?  Is there something about it that didn't work?  I made the assumption that you wanted the label widths to be dynamic.  If you want them to be fixed, add a width constraint to each label.

Comment: Hi VacaWama, thanks for your answer, this is exactly what I was searching for. There is more constraints than with a stack view, but I can customize distances between labels and baselines alignments with exactly what I need. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Stack View for this:

[image]

In the 'Attribute Inspector' you can set for example that each text field has an equal width and a spacing of 5 points between them:

[image]

You can then use your Stack View to center horizontally like your normally would do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this tip. Tried it but in my exemple I don't have the same spaces between labels, and with the stack view they must be all the same.

Comment: Did you set fill equally?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see, I can't put horizontal constraints between my labels if they are in a stack view.